# How to print all items from ListBox to a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to display all elements from a ListBox to a TextBox. I'm not sure how to do this, I have tried doing foreach statement but it doesn't work for the reason that ListBox doesn't contain IEnumerator.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried ListBox.Items?

Comment: [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) or [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx), i mean WebForms or WinForms?

Comment: It's trivial: you just need to loop though ListViewItems collection and build string, then display this string in textBox.

Comment: @Disposer: ListViewItems even if it's ListBox not ListView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Items collection of Winforms Listbox returns a Collection type of Object so you can use `ToString()` on each item to print its text value as below:

```
string text = "";
foreach(var item in yourListBox.Items) 
{
    text += item.ToString() + "/n"; // /n to print each item on new line or you omit /n to print text on same line
}
yourTextBox.Text = text;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (ListItem liItem in listBox1.Items)
     textBox1.Text += liItem.Value + " "; // or .Text
```

EDIT:

Since you're using WinForms, `ListBox.Items` returns an `ObjectCollection`

```
foreach (object liItem in listBox1.Items)
     textBox1.Text += liItem.ToString() + " "; // or .Text
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. ListItems causes an error. When I change to ListBox then liItem.Value causes error.

Comment: @HelpNeeder didn't get you right, what's your new error again?

Comment: I'm getting: The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Try running your foreach on Listbox.Items..that has an enumerator that you can use